# Swift avoid repeating code in initializer

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

How can I avoid repeating code between my initialisers? I want the dateFormatter to remain a let constant.

```
let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter

init() {
    dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is **really** the actual code replace the entire code with

```
lazy var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter = {
   let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
   formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
   formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
   return formatter
}()
```

The variable is lazily initialized once when it's accessed the first time

Edit: It's also possible to declare the variable as constant without the lazy attribute.

```
let dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter = { ...
```

The difference is that the formatter is created immediately (**not** lazily) during the initialization of the instance.

**Edit:**

In Swift 3 `NSDateFormatter` has been renamed to `DateFormatter`
 and `.MediumStyle` to `.mediumStyle`

Comment: for it to be lazy, you need to add the lazy prefix here right? and change let to var. otherwise the date formatter logic won't be laxity instantiated but instead called each time it is accessed.

Comment: No, you can use both forms, I just tested it in a Playground.

Comment: `NOTE

You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.`
 [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Laffen, I edited the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you could [set the default property value of the date formatter using a closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232).

Then your property declaration becomes:

```
let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

and you can remove the date formatter bits from your initialisers.

Answer (score 0):

That's the only way I could think of:

```
class Sample: UIViewController {
    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        setupDateFormatter()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupDateFormatter()
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        setupDateFormatter()
    }

    private func setupDateFormatter() {
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I have edited my post if your interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to setup a property, then I would go for vadian's way.  But your setup code requires some procedure like preparing complex directly structure or preparing image caches, then I like to go for lazy var closure trick.  This setup closure executes only once, just like any other lazy var properties are initialized once.  So you can write pretty complex enough procedural code here.  Don't forget add `private` then your subclasses won't interfere your business.

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)!
        self.setup()
    }

    override init?(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)
    }

    lazy private var setup: ()->() = {
        // do some complex procedure here!!
        return {}
    }()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm specifically interested in how to assign values to let constants, which must be executed within an init method.